# What does it mean when "a manuscript has communicated in a journal"?

Tags: word-usage

What does it mean when "a manuscript has communicated in a journal" ?
I came across the sentence at work. Does it mean the manuscript was made public in the journal,
or just sent to the journal? Or something different?

Comment: What do you mean "at work"?  Was this in a newspaper or a website? or did some say it to you? Are you sure of the exact words?  Can you give some more context?  At the moment it looks very odd, but it might make sense in some contexts. Try to quote the whole paragraph.  You haven't quoted a complete sentence.  If you can link to a source that is perfect.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. This was on a researcher's job report that I'm supposed to translate, that is to describe what they've achieved. The exact sentence was "a manuscript '(title of the manuscript)' has communicated in '(title of the journal)'". Sorry if this isn't enough. I didn't quote the whole thing because it might violate work rules.

Comment: It probably just means "was published" but I think we would need more context to be confident.

Comment: It was a brief report and there wasn't much, I'm afraid. But thanks anyway for your help. I really appreciate it. Hope you stay safe.